# Java socket giving premature end of stream

Tags: java, sockets, xmpp

I'm setting up a comet server that connects to a XMPP server.  Here's how it goes down:

A client connects with the comet server and, among other things, a socket connection is opened:

```
try {
        radio = new Socket("server", 5222);
        out = new PrintWriter(radio.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(radio.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host: "+e);
        error = e.toString();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error: "+e);
        error = e.toString();
    }
```

Next, a thread is started, which waits for data from the socket:

```
public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started.");
        String data;
        String error;
        Client remote;
        Client client;
        while(!done) {
            data = this.output();
            remote = bayeux.getClient(remoteId);
            client = bayeux.getClient(clientId);
            if(data!=null) {
                Map<String, Object> packet = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                packet.put("xml", data);
                remote.deliver(client, "/radio/from", packet, null);
            }
            error = this.error();
            if(error!=null) {
                Map<String, Object> packet = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                packet.put("details", error);
                remote.deliver(client, "/radio/error", packet, null);
            }
            /* try { 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
            }  
            catch (InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted!"); } */
        }

        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            radio.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error disconnecting: "+e);
            error = e.toString();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread stopped.");
    }

    public String output() {
        try {
            String data = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("From: "+data);
            if(data==null) {
                System.out.println("End of stream!");
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //error = "End of stream.";
                //this.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.toString();
            System.out.println("IO error! "+e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any input received from the client is forwarded to the XMPP server:

```
    public void input(String xml) {
        System.out.println("To: "+xml);
        out.println(xml);
    }
```

So here's where the problem come in.  The client opens the connection and sends the proper XML to the XMPP server to start a stream.  `in.readLine();` hangs, as it should, until a response is received from the server.  As soon as it is received, `in.readLine();` begins to return null, over and over again.  This shouldn't happen; it should hang until it receives data.  It seems unlikely that the server has closed out on me, it hasn't sent the `</stream:stream>` to signal the end of an XMPP stream.  Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You say it's unlikely that the server closes the connection, but just to be safe, did you really check what radio.isConnected() returns after readLine() returns null?

Comment: It's too bad you didn't just use BOSH (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html), or you could have used something off-the-shelf for either the client, the server, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the XMPP connection can and will give you incomplete stanzas, or multiple stanzas in a single read.  If your COMET connection expects that what you're passing it is well-formed XML, you will have issues.  As well, XMPP is not newline-terminated, so I'm not sure why you expect `readLine()` to be terribly useful.

Next, are you doing synchronous I/O on two different sockets on the same thread?  Sounds like a recipe for a deadlock.  If you insist on going down this path (instead of just using [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html)), I'd strongly urge you to use NIO, instead of your sleep hack.

Comment: I'll give NIO a shot, although I read somewhere that on modern linux systems (I think POSIX was mentioned) threaded sockets are actually more efficient than NIO. But I think some recoding would be good nomatter what, the code kinda sucks XD

Comment: And good call on the readLine not being useful with XML, it was a stupid thing to do.